# the file @(ReferenceCopyLocalPath->; WithMetadatavalue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference')-> to be packed was not found on disk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard

I am creating a nuget package using the pack command that is in dot net standard and its generating the following error:

```
the file @(ReferenceCopyLocalPath->; WithMetadatavalue('ReferenceSourceTarget',
 'ProjectReference')-> to be packed was not found on disk
```

Below is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    <PropertyGroup>
           <Version>1.4.3.8</Version>
           <PackageVersion>$(Version)</PackageVersion>
           <PackageOutputPath>..\build_output\packages</PackageOutputPath>
           <TargetFrameworks>net461;netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp3.0;net462;net47;net471;net472;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
           <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
           <AssemblyVersion>$(Version)</AssemblyVersion>
           <FileVersion>$(Version)</FileVersion>
           <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
           <Authors>sn.synergy</Authors>
           <Company>Gyldendal™</Company>
           <PackageTags>Logger;Logging;Manager</PackageTags>
           <Copyright>© Gyldendal</Copyright>
           <PackageProjectUrl>https://gyldendaldenmark.visualstudio.com/Common
     Components/_git/logger</PackageProjectUrl>
           <RepositoryUrl>https://gyldendaldenmark.visualstudio.com/Common Components/_git/logger</RepositoryUrl>
           <RootNamespace>LoggingManager</RootNamespace>    </PropertyGroup>    <PropertyGroup
     Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
           <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
           <DebugType>full</DebugType>
           <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>    </PropertyGroup>    <ItemGroup>
           <None Include="NLog.config">
              <Pack>true</Pack>
           </None>    </ItemGroup>    <ItemGroup>
           <None Update="NLog.xsd">
              <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
           </None>    </ItemGroup>    <!--Common Package-->    <ItemGroup>
           <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.6.7" />    </ItemGroup>    <!--Trageting .NET CORE (2.1, 3.0) && .NET STANDARD
     (2.0,2.1) -->    <ItemGroup
     Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netcore')) OR
     $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard'))">
           <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
           <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />-->
           <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.6.1" />
           <PackageReference Include="NLog.WindowsEventLog" Version="4.6.7" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="4.6.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.6.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.7.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.6.0" />    </ItemGroup>    <!--Targeting .NET FRAMEWORK
     (4.6.1 4.6.2)  -->    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' ==
     'net461' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">
           <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" />
           <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.5.4" />
           <PackageReference Include="NLog.WindowsEventLog" Version="4.6.7" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="4.5.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.1" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.5.0" />    </ItemGroup>    <!--Targeting .NET FRAMEWORK
     (4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2)-->    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'
     == 'net47' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472'">
           <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" />
           <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.5.4" />
           <PackageReference Include="NLog.WindowsEventLog" Version="4.6.7" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="4.5.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.1" />
           <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
           <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.5.0" />    </ItemGroup>    <ItemGroup>
           <Folder Include="Properties\" />    </ItemGroup>    <ItemGroup>
           <ProjectReference Include="..\LoggingManager.Nlog.RabbitMQ.Target\LoggingManager.Nlog.RabbitMQ.Target.csproj">
              <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
           </ProjectReference>    </ItemGroup>    <PropertyGroup>
           <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
           <!-- include PDBs in the NuGet package -->
           <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
     </PropertyGroup>    <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage"
     DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
           <ItemGroup>
              <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget',
     'ProjectReference')->;WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'all'))" />
           </ItemGroup>    </Target>    <ItemGroup>
           <Content Include="NLog.config">
              <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
           </Content>    </ItemGroup>    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="pack">
           <Exec Command="nuget push &quot;$(PackageOutputPath)\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg&quot;
     -ApiKey 24FCB347-75E6-41D6-BF80-E49CB142C092 -Source &quot;https://gyldendalnugetserver.azurewebsites.net/nuget&quot;
     -ConfigFile &quot;..\.nuget\nuget.config&quot;&#xD;&#xA;nuget push &quot;$(PackageOutputPath)\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).symbols.nupkg&quot;
     -ApiKey 24FCB347-75E6-41D6-BF80-E49CB142C092 -Source &quot;https://gyldendalnugetserver.azurewebsites.net/nuget&quot;
     -ConfigFile &quot;..\.nuget\nuget.config&quot;&#xD;&#xA;Exit /B 0&#xD;&#xA;" />    </Target> </Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have multiple typos.

For example

```
<BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget',
 'ProjectReference')->;WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'all'))" />
```

should be

```
<BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget',
 'ProjectReference')->WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'all'))" />
```

I.e. you should remove semicolon symbol after `->` symbols

Probably it is the result of manual changes after automatic replaces of `->` by `&gt;`